# Understanding the difference between $\partial f, \mathcal{D}_{f^{*}}, f^{*}, \partial f^{*}$ for a specific set of functions

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

I am trying to calculate the following quantities: $\partial f, \mathcal{D}_{f^{*}}, f^{*}, \partial f^{*}$ for the following functions:

1. $f(x) = x^2, \mathcal{D}_{f} = \mathbb{R}$.
2. $f(x) = |x|, \mathcal{D}_{f} = \mathbb{R}$.
3. $f(x) = e^x, \mathcal{D}_{f} = \mathbb{R}$.
4. $f(x) = \dfrac{|x|^{p}}{p}, \mathcal{D}_{f} = \mathbb{R}, p>1$.
5. $f(x) = x \log x-x+1, f(0) = 1, \mathcal{D}_{f} = [0, + \infty]$.

I am completely lost, seeing that as far as my study goes I have not been taught how to "calculate" them, other than the relatively well known [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative).

Any pointers would be more than welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Any book with *Convex Analysis* in the title will help you. The function in 2 is sublinear so its conjugate must be an indicator function. I find the following formula very useful for computing the subdifferential:

$$\partial f(x) = \mathbb{R} \cap [f'_-(x),f'_+(x)],$$

where $f'_{\pm}$ are the one-sided derivatives from Calculus I.

Comment: I specifically asked the difference between the 4 types of subdifferentiation above. 

Saying "open any convex analysis book" is certainly no pointer, and certainly of no help.

Comment: Start with 1. What is the definition of the conjugate? You can find the maximum in the definition by Calculus I techniques. Do you know how to take a derivative, set it equal to $0$, find the critical point, and plug it back into the objective function? That will give you the solution to 1.